# Getting data from localhost using Angular and Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, angular, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on build an web app using Angular and Spring Boot. I am trying to get data from localhost but I get nothing.

This is **the json data** from the server

[image]

And this my **service ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {map, catchError} from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {Entreprise} from '../modules/entreprise';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EntrepriseService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {  }


  public getEntreprises():Observable<Entreprise>{

    return this.http.get<Entreprise>("http://localhost:8080/entreprises/all");

            }

}
```

And this is **component ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EntrepriseService } from '../services/entreprise.service';
import {Entreprise} from '../modules/entreprise';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})


export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

entreprises:Entreprise;


  constructor(private entrepriseService:EntrepriseService) { }

  public onGetEntreprises(){

    return this.entrepriseService.getEntreprises().
   subscribe(data =>{
      this.entreprises = data;

      console.log(data);
    });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {



  }

}
```

And this is the **html template**

```
<h4>entreprises</h4>
<button (click)="onGetEntreprises()">get </button>

<p *ngFor="let ee of entreprises">{{ee.content.name}}</p>
```

And this is the error I get when I click on the button

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not using https?

Comment: no i'm not using https

Comment: What have to you tried to debug this issue. I don't see any issue. But for the sake of debugging use a plain JavaScript file and use a fetch request like this:

fetch("http://localhost:8080/entreprises/all")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you should add an `*ngIf` to your `p` tag, since you could get null errors if the array of `Enterprise` is not initialized (it is `async` => API call).

---

Also, this is the actual problem, you defined a single model class reference, but not an array, which is actually what gets returned by your backend.

Probably, it would be better practice if you did this:

```
this.enterprise = data.content
```

While `this.enterprises` looks somewhat like this:

```
enterprises: Enterprise[];
```

---

Furthermore, you probably have not implemented a CORS policy on the Spring side of things. Here is a good article about that: [CORS with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors).
For testing purposes, add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` to your `@RestController` class. This is good for development, but in production you should defo don't do this, since this would allow all origins to request your API.

---

***More tips:***

- Be sure that your model classes on the Angular side of things do actually have all fields which come from the backend.
- Are you sure that you have imported the `HttpClientModule`?

---

Update your question to tell me if it works.

Comment: thanks it works .. i added @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") to my server  and it worked